# Is there a way to get CSS XSS in modern browsers?

Tags: css, browser, xss, internet-explorer-10

I wanted to know if there's any way to get CSS Style XSS on modern browsers?

For example, on older IE browsers the following is susceptible:

```
<div style="width:expression(prompt('XSS'))">
```

Comment: If the HTML is built dynamically as text and the data used for the style attribute (eg) is not escaped then HTML-injection is still possible; but I suspect that is not what is being asked for.

Comment: Could you explain what do you intent to use this for? There may be alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. As this example perfectly illustrates, Javascript (or any scripting) has no place in CSS, therefore XSS (the second S is for 'Scripting') is not possible. CSS should be declarative only, and is when implemented conforming to the W3 standards. Dynamic expressions are now done with `calc` which can only evaluate simple mathematical expressions, without resorting to the JS engine.

`expression` was an IE-only hack to facilitate specific features until W3 came up with an alternative. As `calc` appeared, `expression` was deprecated. Starting with IE11, [`expression` is no longer supported in the Internet Zone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384050(v=vs.85).aspx). It was [announced in 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx) that it would end up this way, specifically citing *'to reduce the attack surface'* as one of the core reasons. In older versions than IE11 it has already been for quite a while only supported in *quirks mode* and *IE7 emulation mode* anyway.

Summarizing: CSS has no place for Javascript, and as such cannot be attacked with XSS when implemented properly as it is in every current browser.

Comment: Is "should *not* be possible" or "no longer possible in IE" (as opposed to "not possible").

Comment: As said, support for `expression` in public sites was completely dropped in IE11, and has been severely limited for some years. Therefore, barring bugs and unknown exploits, it should not be possible.